# Posting reverse time on php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I'm having a problem with the time on my news section. The numbers of time is correct, but when it's actually pm, it posted am and vice versa.

Here's the codes:

**insertnews.php**

```
<?php

$news = $_POST['news'];

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$dateposted = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "chess");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into news(dateposted,news) values( '$dateposted', '$news')");

header('location: newslist.php');

?>
```

**newslist.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("chess") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news")
or die(mysql_error());

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($numrows == 0) {
    echo "No news";
} else {
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td><b>Date Posted</b></td><td><b>News</b></td></tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $currentDateTime = $row['dateposted'];
        $newDateTime     = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', strtotime($currentDateTime));
        echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $newDateTime . "</td> <td>" . $row['news'] . "</td><td><a href='editnews.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='deletenews.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete</a></td></tr>";


    }
    echo "</table>";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

I don't understand if how can I fix this problem.

Comment: `var_dump($currentDateTime);` -- What do you get?

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). And isn't it better to save times as a timestamp? This way, you can easily adjust the displaying of a date afterwards.

Comment: @AmalMurali `string '2014-01-06 12:02:16' (length=19)
string '2014-01-06 12:01:44' (length=19)
string '2014-01-06 12:12:21' (length=19)
string '2014-01-06 12:20:54' (length=19)
string '2014-01-06 12:32:53' (length=19)`

Comment: Use the `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` (24 hour notation) when writing to the database.
Otherwise the " PM" (or " AM") part just gets truncated, leaving you with always "AM" situation. Or you can use the **MySQL** [**NOW()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function to store current time. @pingboo23

Comment: See also the following bug in PHP 5.2.6 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46589 if that's your PHP version. @pingboo23

Comment: @Fred-ii- I already used it. Still the same.

Comment: And what about using the [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function?

Comment: I'm confused on how to use `NOW()` in my code. And where to put it. @Fred-ii-

Comment: I suggest that you create a test table with the same code that you have now, then instead of using `$dateposted = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());` and `INSERT into news(dateposted,news)` you can drop `$dateposted = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());` and just use `INSERT into news(NOW(),news)` @pingboo23 You can also Google "how to enter date using NOW() mysqli php"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila'));
echo $date->format('Y/m/d h:i:s a');
```

remove this line

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

from here

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); //don't need this line anymore
        $currentDateTime = $row['dateposted'];
        $newDateTime     = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', strtotime($currentDateTime));
        echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $newDateTime . "</td> <td>" . $row['news'] . "</td><td><a href='editnews.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='deletenews.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
}
```